# How do you add comments in a VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I have some VBScripts I would like to add my explanation to within the code.

Is there some syntax for adding a comment?

Comment: You know you should do some research before posting, right? Like googling or trying to find the answer in a manual or something first. https://www.google.com/search?q=comment+in+vbscript&oq=comment+in+vbscr&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j69i60j0l3.7904j0j7&client=ms-android-huawei&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I use `'///////` on start of lines for important comments and a single `'` for minor comments

Comment: Surprisingly although this is a very basic topic there is no hard and fast answer on [so] for it. Because of this, I've added an answer.

Comment: Why did you un-accept my answer, was there something wrong with it?

Answer (score 14):

#### How do you comment code in VBScript?

If in doubt, review [The Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//273zc69c%28v%3dvs.85%29)

> <sup>Taken from [Rem Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//kyyd7ef1%28v%3dvs.85%29)</sup>
> *As shown in the syntax section, you can use an apostrophe (`'`) instead of the `Rem` keyword. If the `Rem` keyword follows other statements on a line, it must be separated from the statements by a colon. However, when you use an apostrophe, the colon is not required after other statements.*

Below is example using both methods

```
Rem This is a comment
'This is also a comment

Call SomeFunction(SomeValue) : Rem This is an inline comment
Call SomeFunction(SomeValue) 'This is also an inline comment
```

There is no real reason to use `Rem` it's [just a throw back from BASIC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1297487/692942). The apostrophe approach works just as well as it is less intrusive in my opinion but it is entirely user preference.

#### What about block comments?

VBScript does not support block comments. Each line must start with either `Rem` or an Apostrophe `'` (multiple variations make no syntactical difference).

---

#### Useful Links

- [Server-side comments: What's the equivalent of <%— --%> in ASP Classic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4431170/692942) *(Applies to comments in [asp-classic](/questions/tagged/asp-classic) which uses [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript))*